# Limitar eager loading en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy haciendo mi menu desplegable de un blog el cual pcarga las categorias de sitio y en hover sobre categorias me muestra los blog de esas categorias lo que deseo es que me muestre hasta un maximo de 4 entradas por categoria en el menu de esa furma se mantiene mas limpio y obligo a los usuarios a entrar a la categoria

les paso el codigo de mi controlador

```
public function index() {
        $secciones = seccion::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(6);
        $categorias = categoria::all();
        $blog = \App\blog::all();
        return view('inicio.index', [
            'secciones' => $secciones,
            'categorias' => $categorias,
            'blogs' => $blog
        ]);
    }
```

tambien les paso la parte de mi blade donde ejecuto el @forelse del el menu

```
@forelse($categorias as $categoria)
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="{{route('categoria.individual', [$categoria->id])}}">{{$categoria->titulo}}</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            @forelse($blogs as $blog)
                @if($blog->categoria_id == $categoria->id)
                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="gallery-1-column.html">{{$blog->titulo}}</a></li>
                @endif
            @empty
                <li>CARGA LOS BLOGS</li>
            @endforelse
        </ul>
    </li>
@empty
    <li>CARGA LAS CATEGORIAS</li>
@endforelse
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente lo más correcto según la forma como funciona Laravel, sería aprovechar las relaciones de Eloquent, sin embargo, hacer esto que buscas no es muy fácil con Eloquent y no es una funcionalidad incluida.

---

Asumiendo que tienes las relaciones correctamente definidas, podemos hacer algo así:

```
$categorias = categoria::with('blogs')->get();
```

Normalmente intentaríamos hacer algo así para buscar limitar los resultados de Eager Loading por cada categoría:

```
$categorias = categoria::with(['blogs' => function ($query) {
    $query->take(4);
}])->get();
```

Pero esto **NO funciona** para limitar los blogs por cada categoría, lo que hace es limitar todos los blogs a solo 4, sin importar si están atados a una sola categoría, las demás categorías aparecerán sin blogs relacionados.

Este inconveniente ha sido planteado como bug en varias ocasiones en Laravel, e incluso alguien lo propuso para Laravel 5.8, pero fue rechazado por su creador y único administrador, Taylor Otwell: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/26035

La solución propuesta en dicho PR ahora es un paquete independiente que permite a Eloquent hacer esto:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function ($query) {
    $query->latest()->limit(10);
}])->get();
```

En este ejemplo se obtienen máximo 10 posts por cada usuario, agregando dicha funcionalidad a Eloquent, y resolviendo el problema de esta pregunta.

El paquete se encuentra en: https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit

Answer (score -1):

Te dejo una forma de hacerlo sin necesidad de estar incorporando paquetes extras. Lo que vamos a hacer es usar groupBy para agrupar nuestros blogs por categoría, luego vamos a recorrer cada grupo con map() y vamos a obtener solo los primeros 4 blogs con slice().

Vamos a modificar la consulta de tus blogs dejándola así:

```
 $blog = \App\blog::all()
                  ->groupBy("categoria_id ") // vamos a agrupar por categoria_id 
                  ->map(function ($group) {
                      return $group->slice(0,4); 
                  });;
```

Lo anterior te va a retornar algo así:

```
{
  "1": [ //Este valor corresponde a "categoria_id", esta categoría tiene 2 posts.
    {
      "id": 1,
      "titulo": "fran",
      ...
      otras columnas...
      ...
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "titulo": "fran islas",
      ...
      otras columnas...
      ...
    },
  ],

  "2": [ //Este valor corresponde a "categoria_id", esta categoría tiene 1 post.
    {
      "id": 3,
      "titulo": "fran",
      ...
      otras columnas...
      ...
    },    
  ],
}
```

Bien, una vez comprendida la estructura que vamos a obtener, vamos a usar estos datos en la vista. Teniendo en cuenta que ya tenemos la key correspondiente al id de cada categoría, ya no hay necesidad de hacer la siguiente validación:

```
@if($blog->categoria_id == $categoria->id)
```

Lo que podemos hacer ahora es indicarle a nuestro `forelse` que recorre el grupo que le corresponde a la categoria actual(`forelse` padre). Lo podemos hacer del siguiente modo:

```
@forelse($blogs[$categoria->id] as $blog)

                    <li class="menu-item"><a href="gallery-1-column.html">{{$blog->titulo}}</a></li>

            @empty
                <li>CARGA LOS BLOGS</li>
            @endforelse
```

Al hacer esto estamos optimizando considerablemente el `forelse`. Si tenemos 5 (4 posts cada una) categorías, vamos a iterar 20 veces en total, anteriormente re realizaba 20 iteraciones en cada categoría para verificar que se corresponda `$blog->categoria_id == $categoria->id` los que nos da un total de 100. En fin, esto tampoco vas a notarlo seguramente en el funcionamiento pero está bueno para tenerlo en cuenta. Si los datos llegan a ser monstruosos, puede bajar considerablemente el rendimiento. Saludos!

Comment: Buffff, se ve bien complejo, pero mil gracias, Voy a ponerlo en práctica ni bien llegue a casa, me da miedo cuando llegue a la sección documentos del perfil, los cuales guardan archivos por usuarios



Porcierto una duda más, se que tendría que abrir otro post pero la concateno rápido,

Tengo una imagen de perfil, Esta guardada bajo el método storage, parece ser que solo se ve si es que el usuario está logrado, tengo que cambiar ese método y guardarla en public si es que quiero que se vea cierto?

Comment: Tranquilo, no es nada complejo... solo cambié una linea de código. Leelo nuevamente con atención y vas a comprenderlo :). Respecto a tu otra duda, no lo se a ciencia cierta, pero me arriesgo a decir que no tiene nada que ver con la ruta del archivo. Para determinar si la muestras o no, debes estar haciendo uso del middleware auth de laravel en tu vista, es lo mas probable.   Proba el código y cualquier duda la consultas. Saludos!