# Paginar y ordenar una tabla entre 4 tablas relacionadas con eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Necesito limitar siempre a 4 los registros de tareas que quiero mostrar en mi vista, y que el ultimo registro se vea en la parte superior de la lista.

Mi código:

```
$lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos', 'proyectos.clientes'])
->with(['proyectos.tareas', 'proyectos.tareas.users'])->get();
```

Necesito paginar y ordenar la tabla tareas.

Pude solucionar parcialmente instalando este paquete para eloquent 
[**eloquent-eager-limit**](https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-eager-limit)

Pude limitar el numero de tareas y ordenarlo como queria de esta manera

```
$lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos', 'proyectos.clientes'])
->with(['proyectos.tareas' => function ($query) {
    $query->latest()->limit(4);
} ])    ->get();
```

El problema es que aun no puedo hacer esa consulta trayendo tambien el usuario por cada tareas cosa que antes podia hacer con la vieja consulta

Comment: Hace poco hicieron una pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/232415/limitar-eager-loading-en-laravel

Comment: me ayudo un poco pero me falta algo que acabo de describir en mi pregunta

Comment: ¿Qué error aparece al traer a los usuarios?

Comment: el error es que ya nome limita a los ultimos 4 registros, si no que me trae todos            $lista_principal = Lista_principal::with(['proyectos', 'proyectos.clientes'])
->with(['proyectos.tareas.users' => function ($query) {
    $query->latest()->limit(4);
} ])    ->get();